# Why does this series diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a_n=\frac{4^n n!}{n^n}$ be a series. Why does it diverge? I got that $a_n\le a_{n+1}$, but $n^n$ is rising much faster than $4^n$ and $n!$?

Comment: As usual, look at Stirlings approximation.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=4\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n}\rightarrow \frac{4}{e}>1$

Comment: Yes, that is true, but we also have that for $e_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n: e_n< e_{n+1}$ but it converges to e.

Comment: In this case this limit is equal $1$, but doesn't matter - you have right, it works for $\sum a_n$ not for $a_n$. You should check that this series is unbounded. As was said before try you Stirling's approximation to estimate $n!$ from below. Then you obtain that $a_n$ is bounded from below by unbounded sequence.

Comment: The problem is not to have an increasing sequence, but to apply the ratio test.

Comment: Can I bound $(\frac{n}{3})^n\le n! \le (\frac{n}{2})^n$?

Answer (score 1):

An idea opposite to mikis': as obviously all the terms are positive, put

$$b_n=\frac{n^n}{4^nn!}\implies \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\frac14\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac e4<1\implies$$

$$\sum_{n+1}^\infty b_n\;\;\;\text{converges}\;\;\implies b_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\implies\frac1{b_n}=\frac{4^nn!}{n^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) note that $$ \frac{4^n n!}{n^n} \sim_{+\infty} \frac {4^n\sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n}{n^n}=\sqrt{2\pi n} (\frac{4}{e})^n$$ but this last series diverges.